# How load and save entire file from blobstore, using only BlobKey?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I want to service file (edit), that user uploaded to server. After saving it to blobstore, I want to load it to memory for editing. After storing file I got `BlobKey` in return. As I understand, I should use the following method to load it into memory:

```
byte[] BlobstoreService.fetchData(BlobKey blobKey, long startIndex, long endIndex)
```

The problem is that I do not know how big the file is, so I do not know what to pass as the `endIndex` variable. How, having only `BlobKey`, do I load a file from blobstore, change it, save new version and recive new `BlobKey` of changed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [javadoc reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfoFactory), seems like you can load a BlobInfo object that will contain your size. You just need to call

```
BlobInfoFactory() bif = New BlobInfoFactory();
BlobInfo bi = bif.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
long size = bi.getSize();
```